# Change CGRect of SpriteSheet Frame - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to change the CGRect of a frame in a spritesheet? My problem is that I have two buttons, but I press the buttons on the device and they aren't always (I guess the term would be registering) registering with the iPhone. I was thinking it was because I am using "CGRectContainsPoint(leftB.boundingBox, touchLocation))" and the image is a little small.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

pause = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pause.png"];
pause.position=ccp(25,65);
[self addChild:pause];

CGRect pauseRect =CGRectMake([pause position].x - [pause contentSize].width, 
                    [pause position].y - [pause contentSize].height, 
                    3*[pause contentSize].height, 3*[pause contentSize].width);


    if (CGRectContainsPoint(pauseRect, location)) {
        NSLog(@"Your touch detected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution by tapping you can create a small sprite that would checked for intersection with your button. `CGRectIntersectsRect()`